# How to run a loop inside a loop for a gam object

Tags: r, gam

I am trying to predict new observations after multiple imputation. Both the newdata and the model to use are list objects. The correctness of the approach is not the issue but how to use the predict function after multiple imputation we I have a new data that is a list. Below are my code.

```
library(betareg)
library(mice)
library(mgcv)
data(GasolineYield)
dat1 <- GasolineYield

dat1 <- GasolineYield
dat1$yield <- with(dat1,
ifelse(yield > 0.40 | yield < 0.17,NA,yield)) # created missing values

datim <- mice(dat1,m=30) #imputing missing values
mod1 <- with(datim,gam(yield ~ batch + emp,family=betar(link="logit"))) #fit models using gam
```

creating data set to be used for prediction

```
datnew <- complete(datim,"long")
datsplit <- split(datnew,datnew$.imp)
```

the code below just testing out the predict without newdata. The problem I observed was that tp is saved as 1 by 32 matrix instead of 30 by 32 matrix. But the print option prints out a 30 by 32 but then I couldn't save it as such.

```
tot <- 0
for(i in 1:30){
tot <- mod1$analyses[[i]]
tp <- predict.gam(tot,type = "response")
print(tp)
}
```

the code below is me trying to predict new observation using newdata. Here I am just lost I am not sure how to go about it.

```
datnew <- complete(datim,"long")
datsplit <- split(datnew,datnew$.imp)
tot <- 0
for(i in 1:30){
tot <- mod1$analyses[[i]]
tp <- predict.gam(tot,newdata=datsplit[[i]], type = "response")
print(tp)
}
```

Can someone help me out on how best to go about it?

Comment: What packages you are you using? Show the `library()` calls. I wouldn't use `with()` around a model function - that's what the `data` argument is for. Things to note, make sure each component of `datsplit` contains all the variables used in the original model.

Comment: I am using the following libraries: mice,mgcv and betareg. The with function is to run model for each of the imputation data set

Comment: You don't need `with()`; that's what the `data` argument of `gam()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find solved the problem. Here is the solution:

```
datnew <- complete(datim,"long")# stack all the imputation data
```

## though I have to point out that this should be your new dataset

I am assuming that this is not used in building the model. My aim of opening this #thread was to address the question of how to predict observations using new data after multiple imputation/using model built with multiple imputation dataset.

```
datsplit <- split(datnew,datnew$.imp)
tot <- list()
tot_ <- list()
for(i in 1:30){
for(j in 1:30){
tot[[j]] <- predict.gam(mod1$analyses[[i]],newdata=datsplit[[j]])
}
tot_[[i]] <- tot
}
# flatten the lists within lists
totfl <- tot_ %>% flatten()
#nrow is the number of observations to be predicted as contained in the 
#newdata set (datsplit)
totn <- matrix(unlist(totfl),nrow=32) 
apply(totn,1,mean) #takes the means of prediction across the 30 data set
```

I hope this helps those with similar questions. I once came across a question on how to predict newdata after multiple imputation, I guess this will answer some of the questions contained in that thread.